# ModuleNotFoundError on .ipynb

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

This is from a .ipynb jupyter notebook in vscode in windows 10:

even when I  pip install pandas in the terminal it still gives this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 # pip install wheel webencodings jinja2 packaging markupsafe werkzeug flatbuffers libclang typing-extensions wrapt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I tried typing 'pip install pandas' in my vscode terminal and it showed this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\s2hun\desktop\machine learning intro\magic\lib\site-packages (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1.26.0 in c:\users\s2hun\desktop\machine learning intro\magic\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\s2hun\desktop\machine learning intro\magic\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.9.0.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\s2hun\desktop\machine learning intro\magic\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in c:\users\s2hun\desktop\machine learning intro\magic\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\s2hun\desktop\machine learning intro\magic\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

I then ran the cell which contained this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

When I did so the following error appeared:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 # pip install wheel webencodings jinja2 packaging markupsafe werkzeug flatbuffers libclang typing-extensions wrapt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I don't know how to fix this and I have had the same problem installing various other python modules in the past.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your kernel?

Comment: One possible solution is to install pandas from jupyter notebook itself. try `!pip install pandas`

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi , that should be `%pip install pandas` for installing in the same environment that the kernel is running in. Please only recommend current best practices. In 2019 the magic install commands were added to overcome the deficiency with using the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands in a running Jupyter `.ipynb` file. See more about the modern `%pip install` command  [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). ...

Comment: <continued> [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.  And if someone is using Anaconda/conda (which doesn't appear to be the case for OP here), then it is `%conda install conda-forge::pandas` to run inside a notebook cell because always best to pick Anaconda/conda routes to install into environment since in that case it became the primary package manager. (Command based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas).

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for mentioning it. You are right, It's better to recommend the most recent method. I didn't know that and I learned it from you. ;)